# Spring boot + Angular 6 + Heroku

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Criei uma aplicação web onde o front utiliza angular 6 e o back utiliza spring boot.

Meu objetivo no momento é colocar a aplicação online.

No servidor local quando eu executo o spring boot o angular é chamado normalmente, quando eu coloco a aplicação no Heroku apenas os links rest funcionam, quando eu tento acessar uma rota do angular é me mostrado erro.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Link gerado pelo Heroku: https://sgm1.herokuapp.com/

Link do rest cidade: https://sgm1.herokuapp.com/cidade/listar

Link da aplicação angular: https://sgm1.herokuapp.com/login

Observação: Já fiz as devidas configurações para integrar angular 6 com spring boot e por este motivo que localmente funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maicon a configuração `{ useHash: true }` está sendo habilitada nas rotas de sua aplicação.

Ou seja a url `https://sgm1.herokuapp.com/login` está sendo chamada da seguinte maneira `https://sgm1.herokuapp.com/#/login`.

Não sei se o Heroku fez essa mudança automaticamente ou não. Mas caso queira remover o useHash você vai precisar redirecionar **tudo** que não for a API para o `index.html`.

Comment: Olá Hiago. Obrigado pela ajuda. Mais para resolver o problema eu tive que copiar a build do angular para a pasta dist do Spring boot.

Comment: @MaiconThales que legal, mas indico que você crie uma resposta com o que Você fez para resolver o problema e marque ela como correta ;)